# Who inspires you the most here at SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, fun

SO is a great place to know how sharp people are there and how in-depth knowledge they have. They certainly become a source of inspiration for us. Just wanted to know who are you most inspired by here at SO in terms of good knowledge, quick answers with *great details* and more. Personally, I am really inspired by these two people (of course **[Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)** too) for having great knowledge and ability to sweep away quick votes:

- **[Pascal MARTIN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/138475/pascal-martin)**
- **[Jonathan Sampson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54680/jonathan-sampson)**

So who are you most inspired by?

Comment: move to meta please

Comment: This all depends on what you're interested in.

Comment: -1 for Jonathan Sampson

Comment: SO is about the questions and answers NOT the people (or at least it should be).

Comment: @ChrisF but MSO is about ... ?

Comment: MSO is about Memes .... Just tons of memes... Soon you shall learn the truth: **Everything is a Meme!**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am inspired by the [Waffle Bunny](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37493/what-do-stack-overflow-users-like-for-breakfast/37495#37495). I mean .. ***It's the Waffle Bunny!***

[image: Giant Waffle Bunny of Awesomeness]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/Oolong_last_head_performance.jpg/601px-Oolong_last_head_performance.jpg))</sub>

Comment: @Chacha102: Looks like you are inspired by yourself :) That's really great !!

Answer (score 3):

[Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert)

Answer (score 2):

[Urdnot the Krogan's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/52443/urdnot-the-krogan-has-a-posse) severed Klingon head, who keeps a vigilant watch for [dire](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40436/is-there-anyone-making-actual-physical-badges/40438#40438) [threats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35434/why-was-my-so-question-about-security-reporting-after-a-code-review-closed-not/35439#35439) to the Trilogy-o-sphere and [keeps us all fresh](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39214/advertising-inquiry-a-fresher/39218#39218).

He also serves as the [Official Trilogy Historian](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37435/how-was-200-chosen-as-the-rep-needed-for-reduced-advertising/37436#37436).

Comment: Less flattery, more closing this awful question, quack.

Comment: @Urdnot: can't help with that here.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, [Joel](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky) for his amazing ability to be both a competent programmer and businessman, and for taking a stand for good treatment of programmers.

Comment: +1 Joel is pretty impressive. Don't forget his great writing-abilities too! The same goes for Jeff, on all points as well.